# how to build a Java file that call another javascript file everyday?

Tags: javascript, java, cordova

I'm building a mobile application using Cordova. The Application should push notifications to user with different everyday time schedule.. now in order to get the schedule without a need to open the application, I need a java file to do the task and call another javascript file everyday at 12:00..

Or is there a different way of doing this?

I've looked in Cordova plugins but I couldn't find any..

Thanks in advance ..

Abed

Answer (score 0):

```
package root;

public class CurrentTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    }

}
```

Number of days since January 1st 1970. Set the current day to a variable and check if the variable matches the number of days. If the number of days does not  equal the number returned by the System class, then push notifications to the user.